# Fails to launch browser in cluster using playwright

Tags: testing, playwright, e2e

I am trying to deploy playwright into a cluster using as docker image,
Evrything works fine in local system but as soon as I put it in a pod, gets an error saying

```
1) [webkit] › dummy.spec.js:7:8 › API Designer › Should display data in All Services =============

browserType.launch: Failed to launch: Error: spawn /opt/app/node_modules/@playwright/test/node_modules/playwright-core/.local-browsers/webkit-1699/pw_run.sh ENOENT
=========================== logs ===========================
<launching> /opt/app/node_modules/@playwright/test/node_modules/playwright-core/.local-browsers/webkit-1699/pw_run.sh --inspector-pipe --headless --no-startup-window
[pid=N/A] starting temporary directories cleanup
[pid=N/A] finished temporary directories cleanup
============================================================

    at Object._baseTest.extend.browser.scope [as fn] (/opt/app/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/index.js:226:51)
    at /opt/app/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/fixtures.js:112:81
```

Any suggestion to get rid of this error.

I am running `tests` using node

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exports.runTests = async () => {
const proc = exec(
    `DEBUG=pw:browser* PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=./node_modules/@playwright/test/node_modules/playwright-core/.local-browsers npx playwright test`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`error : ${error}`);
      }
      if (stderr) {
        console.log(`error : ${stderr}`);
      }
    }
  );
  proc.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

it says that you don't have the browsers installed inside the docker container. you could either copy the browsers in your docker and change the env PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH to something else.
or in the dockerfile include npx playwright install

Try out my package playwright-cluster
https://github.com/cnikolov/playwright-cluster